# Does anyone know a js lib for dynamic tables with pagination?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have created a rails controller that returns JSON data. So, I cannot render the data on the server as usual with rails.

I can create a simple JS that can just take the JSON and create a table. But I which to support pagination. I looked a few such tables from jquery plugins but they do not use Bootstrap css, so it looks pretty nasty in my layout.

Has anyone encountered such a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend you using [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/) and [Backbone.Paginator](https://github.com/addyosmani/backbone.paginator). Fits your needs perfectly!